# WATIN on SSIS script component - Single-Threaded Apartment

Tags: ssis, watin, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I need to download a file from a site with forms authentication and further processing the text file with Integration Services.

For the file download I choose to use WATIN, So I imported the Watin library and scripted the browser steps. However when I try to run the code I get an Exception with this Message.

> The CurrentThread needs to have it's
>   ApartmentState set to
>   ApartmentState.STA to be able to
>   automate Internet Explorer.

all this using the 
(with the  method attribute)

If I try to use this line of code to set it to STA

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
```

I get this exception

> Error:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Failed to set the specified COM
>   apartment state.    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState
>   state)

How do I change the SSIS script task to use this Single-Threaded apartment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by creating another Thread with the STA ApartmentState.

The code was like this:

```
Private threadDelegate As ParameterizedThreadStart
Private filesdir As String

<STAThread()> _
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        threadDelegate = New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Me.DoSomething)
        StartBrowserRoutine(threadDelegate)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    Catch
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub StartBrowserRoutine(ByVal threadRoutine As ParameterizedThreadStart)
    Dim dialogThread As Thread = New Thread(threadRoutine)
    dialogThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    dialogThread.Start(Nothing)
    dialogThread.Join(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found your solution very useful for my case that is similar, I add the C# code I used in case someone needs it

```
public void Main() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join(); // wait for thread to end

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

public void DoMethod(object sender) {
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new BrowserWindow("http://x.xxx"));
}
```

And here is the `BrowserWindow` class

```
class BrowserWindow : Form
{
    private string url;

    public BrowserWindow(string url) {
        this.url = url;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        Load += new EventHandler(Window_Load);
    }

    void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.AllowNavigation = true;
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
        wb.Navigate(this.url);
    }

    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser web = sender as WebBrowser;
        // here goes the business logic
    }
}
```

Comment: great, when I did that, there wasn't the possibility to use C# on SSIS, thanks!